# EclipseLink - adding indexing to Postgress

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to add indexing to my existing Entity, exacly on specific column. Following by documentation i wrote something like that:

```
1.first way
@Entity
@Table(name = "potatoe", schema = "mySchema")
public class Potatoe {
(...)
@Index(name = "knife", table = "potatoe", schema = "mySchema")
    private String origin;
(...)
}

2.second way
@Entity
@Table(name = "potatoe", schema = "mySchema")
@Index(name = "knife", columnNames = "origin", table = "potatoe", schema = "mySchema")
public class Potatoe {
(...)
    private String origin;
(...)
}

 3. third way(pure jpa)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "potatoe", schema = "mySchema", indexes = {@javax.persistence.Index(name = "knife", columnList = "origin")})
    public class Potatoe {
    (...)
        private String origin;
    (...)
    }
```

But isnt working, the  INDEX not created. And I always gotted exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error in syntax
>   or/in near "."

Query created by EclipseLink is

> CREATE INDEX myschema.knife ON potatoe
>   (ORIGIN)]]

and i dont know why he change the name of index. Why eclipseLink add schema with dot to name? I suppose that this "." in name of index makeing problem, but I don't know how to delete this.

I'am working on eclipselink ver 2.5.0 and postgresql ver 9.1-901.

edit//
When i delete attribute "schema", eclipselink create properly query:

> CREATE INDEX knife ON potatoe
>   (ORIGIN)]]

but problem is that i must define schema because I have some. So without defined schema its a error about relation(relation not exisit). So its true, because my default relation isn't "myschema".

I check in Postgres and working query is like below but i dont know how to generate this:

> CREATE INDEX knife ON myschema.potatoe (ORIGIN)

Someone have idea?

Comment: seems like a bug - index should not have schema name prepend, but the table should - all the way around

Comment: maybe try ```@Index(name = "knife", columnNames = "origin", table = "potatoe")``` ?..

Comment: @Vao Tsun i try i think all kind of variations of ths annotation and all no works :/

Comment: all with same error?..

Comment: Not exacly, when I no define schema, the errror is "no relation to nameOfDatabase". Its appears because my default schema isnt "mySchema", otherwise error is the same.

Comment: try a monkey hack? `@Index(name = "knife", columnNames = "origin", table = "myschema.potatoe")`

Comment: I didnt think about it, its works :D Thank You :) I cant add "+" to your comment, maybe wrote this like a answer.

Comment: I made it an answer. Probably you should also write to EclipseLink support. This lack seems as serious limitation

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find indeed the s[chema defining for table in docs](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_index.htm#BABGIFEC)
Try a monkey hack:

```
@Index(name = "knife", columnNames = "origin", table = "myschema.potatoe")
```